# Spark 1.6.2 & YARN: diagnostics: Application failed 2 times due to AM Container for exited with exitCode: -1

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a cluster of 2 machines and am trying to submit a spark job with YARN cluster manager.

- vanilla Spark 1.6.2 built aginst hadoop 2.6.2
- vanilla Hadoop 2.7.2

I can successfully run map-reduce jobs and spark jobs with standalone cluster manager. But when I run it with YARN, I got an error.

- Any suggestions how to get it to work?
- How do I enable more verbose logging? The error message is absolutely unclear
- Why no log files are created under hadoop/logs/userlogs/applicationXXX?
- Rhetorical question: IMO: hadoop logging & diagnostic isn't very well. Why is that? Hadoop seems to be an established product.

Below is the output:

```
mike@mp-desktop ~/opt/hadoop $ spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster  ~/prg/scala/spark-examples_2.11-1.0.jar     10
16/07/09 08:59:00 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/07/09 08:59:01 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at mp-desktop/192.168.1.60:8050
16/07/09 08:59:01 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 2 NodeManagers
16/07/09 08:59:01 INFO yarn.Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (8192 MB per container)
16/07/09 08:59:01 INFO yarn.Client: Will allocate AM container, with 1408 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
16/07/09 08:59:01 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
16/07/09 08:59:01 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
16/07/09 08:59:01 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
16/07/09 08:59:02 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/home/mike/opt/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar -> hdfs://mp-desktop:9000/user/mike/.sparkStaging/application_1468043888852_0001/spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar
16/07/09 08:59:06 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/home/mike/prg/scala/spark-examples_2.11-1.0.jar -> hdfs://mp-desktop:9000/user/mike/.sparkStaging/application_1468043888852_0001/spark-examples_2.11-1.0.jar
16/07/09 08:59:06 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-2ee6dfd6-e9d3-4ca4-9e98-5ce9e75dc757/__spark_conf__7114661171911035574.zip -> hdfs://mp-desktop:9000/user/mike/.sparkStaging/application_1468043888852_0001/__spark_conf__7114661171911035574.zip
16/07/09 08:59:06 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: mike
16/07/09 08:59:06 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: mike
16/07/09 08:59:06 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(mike); users with modify permissions: Set(mike)
16/07/09 08:59:07 INFO yarn.Client: Submitting application 1 to ResourceManager
16/07/09 08:59:07 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1468043888852_0001
16/07/09 08:59:08 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1468043888852_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/07/09 08:59:08 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1468043947113
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://mp-desktop:8088/proxy/application_1468043888852_0001/
     user: mike
16/07/09 08:59:09 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1468043888852_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/07/09 08:59:10 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1468043888852_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/07/09 08:59:11 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1468043888852_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/07/09 08:59:12 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1468043888852_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/07/09 08:59:13 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1468043888852_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/07/09 08:59:14 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1468043888852_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/07/09 08:59:15 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1468043888852_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/07/09 08:59:16 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1468043888852_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/07/09 08:59:17 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1468043888852_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/07/09 08:59:18 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1468043888852_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/07/09 08:59:19 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1468043888852_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/07/09 08:59:20 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1468043888852_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/07/09 08:59:21 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1468043888852_0001 (state: FAILED)
16/07/09 08:59:21 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Application application_1468043888852_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1468043888852_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://mp-desktop:8088/cluster/app/application_1468043888852_0001Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: File /home/mike/hadoopstorage/nm-local-dir/usercache/mike/appcache/application_1468043888852_0001/container_1468043888852_0001_02_000001 does not exist
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1468043947113
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://mp-desktop:8088/cluster/app/application_1468043888852_0001
     user: mike
16/07/09 08:59:21 INFO yarn.Client: Deleting staging directory .sparkStaging/application_1468043888852_0001
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1468043888852_0001 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1034)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1081)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
16/07/09 08:59:21 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/07/09 08:59:21 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-2ee6dfd6-e9d3-4ca4-9e98-5ce9e75dc757
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error message I had was similar:

```
16/07/15 13:55:53 INFO Client: Application report for application_1468583505911_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/07/15 13:55:54 INFO Client: Application report for application_1468583505911_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/07/15 13:55:55 INFO Client: Application report for application_1468583505911_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/07/15 13:55:56 INFO Client: Application report for application_1468583505911_0002 (state: FAILED)
16/07/15 13:55:56 INFO Client:
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: Application application_1468583505911_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1468583505911_0002_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://<redacted>:8088/cluster/app/application_1468583505911_0002Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: File does not exist: hdfs://<redacted>:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1468583505911_0002/__spark_conf__4995486282135454270.zip
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://<redacted>:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1468583505911_0002/__spark_conf__4995486282135454270.zip
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$24.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1367)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$24.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1359)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1359)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:253)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:63)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:361)
```

Try running with YARN in client mode instead of cluster mode which prints out the driver program log to your shell:

spark-submit --class myClass **--master yarn** /path/to/myClass.jar

The log output showed that myClass was failing immediately because I had the incorrect number of args (the class expected more than 1 arg).
The class had failed with my custom exit code (42) and prints "Usage" info to the log, allowing me to fix the actual problem.

When I ran with --master yarn-cluster, this output was not visible to me and I could not see the "Usage" information mentioned above. Instead, all I had was the vague "File does not exist" issue shown above.

Specifying the correct number of arguments to myClass resolved the issue.

At this point I've assumed that my Spark job failed so quickly that it started cleaning up the .sparkStaging files it had copied before YARN had checked for them.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have solved your problem but I faced the same issue this morning with Spark 2.1 in yarn cluster and I found this post. I had the same error as you did and my problem was spark conference object which needed:

```
conf = (SparkConf()
         .setMaster("yarn") #I had this value as local
         .setAppName("My app Name")
```

So when I changed this and did my spark submit ( --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster ) everything worked right.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by the following statement and I use CDH5.14.1 and spark 1.6

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --driver-memory 4g \
    --executor-memory 2g \
    --executor-cores 1 \
    --queue thequeue \
    lib/spark-examples*.jar \
    10
```

Here is the link：https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/running-on-yarn.html